# Parameters for Multires Bake

Tags: scripting

I'm trying to find the parameters for the Multires bake command [bpy.ops.object.bake_image()](https://docs.blender.org/api/3.4/bpy.ops.object.html#bpy.ops.object.bake_image) but in the documentation, none is listed. So there isn't any or are they just not listed? Thinking about like the type, switching between Displacement and Normals, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated in the docs you linked, `bpy.ops.object.bake_image()` only runs the baking. As you can guess by it being within `bpy.ops`: it is an operator. The baking settings are part of the scene's data.

If you enable the python tooltips, you can see the settings' pythonic paths:

[image]

You can also <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> > Copy (full) data path.